# Exercise V.4.2 Shafarevich basic algebraic geometry 2

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Find all points of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$.

By definition, $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}=\operatorname{Spec} (\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C})$.
Now, I know that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}^2$; so my question reduces to find the elements of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}^2$. Which is the ring structure in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: You have ${\mathbb C}\otimes_{\mathbb R}{\mathbb C}\cong{\mathbb C}\times{\mathbb C}$ *as rings*, where the right hand side is the ring-theoretical product in which addition and multiplication are defined componentwise.

Comment: If you know $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}^2$ but don't know the ring structure on $\mathbb{C}^2$, then you don't know $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}^2$. Perhaps you meant as sets?

Comment: @Hanno Thanks a lot!! Now I can finish the exercise!